# How can I set time for insertAfter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I set time for insertAfter , more details :

```
$(z).find(".post--"+a).insertAfter(".post:last");
```

for example when i use .slideDown(time) it will slide with the time I set now i want to know how can do that for insertAfter

Comment: I want to set time of insert after . Like .slideDown(time) I want use for .insertAfter()

Comment: So basically you want to animate your `insertAfter`.

Comment: Are you looking for some sort of time delay? `.insertAfter` places an element after another in the DOM hierarchy, not after a time delay. Look into setTimeout.

Comment: But how do you expect the effect to be? Like `slideDown()` then `slideUp()`? If so, call it like that.

Comment: Try something like `$(z).find(".post--"+a).hide().insertAfter(".post:last").slideDown(500);`

Comment: mohkhan , yes i want to do that . @j08691 : can you give me a example for setTimeout with that code ?

Comment: @Doannamthai I'll post it as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I suggested in the comment, you can try

```
$(z).find(".post--"+a).hide().insertAfter(".post:last").slideDown(500);
```

Comment: Another suggestion, similar to this answer: `$(z).find(".post--"+a).slideUp(500, function() { $(this).insertAfter(".post:last").slideDown(500) });`